# Parse.com user becomes anonymous

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my code I convert an anonymous user to a ParseUser, and the data browser shows the converted user with an undefined authData, as it should.

When the app is closed and re-opened, the if statement to check if an anonymous user is linked returns true instead of false, but the authData is still undefined.

We then call a cloud code function to modify the user's friends, and at this point, the current user authData becomes "Anonymous" again, but the username remains the same.

```
//Returns true no matter what
if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
                                mUsernameText.setText("Not Logged In");
                                Log.d("testuser", "tes1");
                            } else {
                                mUsernameText.setText(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                            }

ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground
("addFriend", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void done(String s, ParseException e) {
                                                if (e == null) {
                                                    //ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                                                     //       .increment(NUM_FRIENDS_KEY);
                                                   //When we try to save the user here it becomes anonymous
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
```

Comment: are you sure you are not calling `enableAutomaticUser()` before the condition ? How do you convert from anonymous to parseUser ?

Comment: also try check 'isAuthenticated()' on a user object

Comment: Yes, I am not calling enableAutomaticUser()....when I convert from anonymous to parseUser I am setting the username, password, and firstName field and signing it up as a new user. This converts the anonymous user because the other 'Number' fields I set when the anonymous user was created remain in the data browser.

Comment: idk, make sure your user is updated, before you chek, `isDirty()` should be false;